# rvalue references in C++

Tags: c++

```
   // move constructor
    ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)
        : _p_vals( other._p_vals  )
        , _size( other._size )
    {
        other._p_vals = NULL;
        other._size = 0;
    }
```

I found a tutorial on rvalue references. I don't really understand why we have to set `other._p_vals = NULL;` and `other._size = 0;` 
The author explains:

> But why do we need to set other._p_vals = NULL? The reason is the
>   destructor--when the temporary object goes out of scope, just like all
>   other C++ objects, its destructor will run.

If it does go out of scope and gets destroyed why bother setting `other._p_vals = NULL`

> When its destructor runs,
>   it will free _p_vals. The same _p_vals that we just copied!

I thought we moved not copied, or... am I wrong?

> If we
>   don't set other._p_vals to NULL, the move would not really be a
>   move--it would just be a copy that introduces a crash later on once we
>   start using freed memory. This is the whole point of a move
>   constructor: to avoid a copy by changing the original, temporary
>   object!

Can someone help me understand?!?

Comment: The destructor would have code that does something to `_p_vals` (e.g. `delete`s it). If you do not have those lines, then you are actually copying and not moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this class contains a raw pointer, we can only assume it owns it, and therefore its destructor must look something like:

```
ArrayWrapper::~ArrayWrapper() {
    delete[] _p_vals;
}
```

In this move constructor we are "stealing" the internals of `other`. If we don't blank out the internals of `other` (being careful to leave it in a consistent "empty" state, so also setting `_size = 0`), then when either of `other` or the new object is destroyed, the one that remains will be pointing at some data that has now been deleted.

Sharing internals is a very different pattern to stealing someone else's internals.

Comment: But isn't other a temporary object that will be destroyed anyways?

Comment: Not necessarily, but let's just suppose it is. Then `other` gets destroyed, and in its destructor (assuming it is properly written), `delete`s its `_p_vals`. Then the new object is pointing at garbage.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now!

Comment: And once `other._p_vals` has been set to NULL, `other._size` must be set to 0 otherwise the object would not be in a "valid" state.